# Use VBA custom functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba

Is there a way to use VBA custom functions within SQL Server query?

For instance:

```vb
Function **total**(nb)
total = (nb)*100
End Function
```

```sql
select price from order where price = **total**(5)
```

This can be done easily with MS Access.
Does SQL Server offer this possibility?

Comment: They are called CLR functions. [Create CLR Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Functions in SQL Server can be implemented as T-SQL or SQLCLR. CLR requires a .NET language like VB.NET or C#. You can't use VBA.

Comment: Though there would be no point in doing it for the above as it's simple arithmetic. You can create scalar functions in T-SQL as well, though they can be known poor performance when they aren't able to be inlined (which can only be done in SQL Server 2019+) so it's normally recommended you use an inline table value function. CLR functions should be used only when it's something you cannot do easily, or in a performant manner, in T-SQL; Regex support for example is a *very* common use case for CLR functions in T-SQL.